# Ubuntu 16.04 keyboard shortcut Alt+F4 to get the suspend/shutdown/restart menu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, shutdown, shortcuts

I would like to set a conditional keyboard shortcut (Alt+F4) which shows the suspend/shutdown/restart menu only if it is pressed when the desktop has the focus, otherwise just close the active window.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use this script on Ubuntu MATE which use caja as the file manager.

```
   #!/bin/bash

   activewindowname=$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)
   if [ "$activewindowname" == "x-caja-desktop" ]; then
     gnome-session-quit --power-off
   else
     xdotool windowclose `xdotool getactivewindow`
   fi
```

copy this code, save it as a script and create a custom shorcut for Alt+F4

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to do that on KDE 5 (Plasma), I modified the script above:

```
#!/bin/bash

activewindowname=$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)
if [ "$activewindowname" == "Рабочий стол по умолчанию — Plasma" ]; then
    qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 1 2 3
else
    xdotool windowclose `xdotool getactivewindow`
fi
```

The desktop's `"$activewindowname"` depends on your locale. Run this command in the Konsole and click on the desktop to get the name in your locale:

```
sleep 2s && xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname
```